# Rails Cucumber Unable to Find Field Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara

This is for the EdX Berkeley SaaS class. I'm struggling through the Caypbara scenario one line at a time. What I'm trying to do now is visit the Edit page for a movie and fill in the Director field with a name. In trying to do so, I get the error:

```
And I fill in "Director" with "Ridley Scott"          # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:6
      Unable to find field "Director" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:7:in `/^I fill in "(.*?)" with "(.*?)"$/'
      features/search_for_director.feature:19:in `And I fill in "Director" with "Ridley Scott"'
```

Here's a feature file called search_for_directors.feature

```
Feature: Search for movies by director

  As a movie buff
  So that I can find movies with my favorite director
  I want to include and serach on director information in movies I enter

Background: movies in database

  Given the following movies exist:
  | title        | rating | director     | release_date |
  | Star Wars    | PG     | George Lucas |   1977-05-25 |
  | Blade Runner | PG     | Ridley Scott |   1982-06-25 |
  | Alien        | R      |              |   1979-05-25 |
  | THX-1138     | R      | George Lucas |   1971-03-11 |

Scenario: add director to existing movie
  When I go to the edit page for "Alien"
  And  I fill in "Director" with "Ridley Scott"
  And  I press "Update Movie Info"
  Then the director of "Alien" should be "Ridley Scott"
```

Now here's movie_steps.rb

```
Given(/^the following movies exist:$/) do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |movie|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
    Movie.create(movie)
  end
end
```

And here's web_steps.rb

```
When(/^I go to the edit page for "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  edit_movie_path(arg1)
end

When(/^I fill in "(.*?)" with "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1, arg2|
  fill_in(arg1, :with => arg2)
end
```

Now when I run cucumber, the step where I visit the edit page passes and is green: `When I go to the edit page for "Alien"`, so it seems like the error must have something to do with my views or controller? But I've added the Director field to all these files, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Here's edit.html.haml, which I think should be the only relevant view for this step.

```
-# edit.html.haml using partial

%h1 Edit Existing Movie

= form_tag movie_path(@movie), :method => :put do

  = label :movie, :title, 'Title'
  = text_field :movie, 'title'

  = label :movie, :rating, 'Rating'
  = select :movie, :rating, ['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17']

  = label :movie, :release_date, 'Released On'
  = date_select :movie, :release_date

  = label :movie, :director, 'Director'
  = text_field :movie, 'director'

  = submit_tag 'Update Movie Info'
```

Also, I updated the controller to allow for a Director field to be passed in the params:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :rating, :description, :release_date, :director)
  end
```

Comment: Those sort of errors are usually caused by you not being on the page you think you are. Since this is an edit page, I would guess you need to be logged in to do so, so it is likely you are on the login page, not on movie editing page. Try adding `save_and_open_page` to your step definition, it should open a preview of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I would take to debug this type of situation:

- Install the Launchy gem (https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy)

As the docs say - "With Launchy installed, when rspec is run again, it will launch an unstyled instance of the specific page. It can be especially useful when debugging errors in integration tests."

- Make use of the Capybara method save_and_open_page to verify whether your test in actually on the page you think it is/should be.
- If you are on the correct page but something else seems to be the problem then I would make use of a debugger such as Pry or Byebug (https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) and insert it into my test, to allow me to take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

Without the Movie#edit controller action code it's tough to say exactly, but usually in beginner rails examples the singular actions take an id number to the resource being acted upon (not the title).  This would generally mean that edit_movie_path(xxx) should take the id number of the movie to be edited and not the title of the movie.  If this is the case then you need to change your "I go to the edit page for ..." step to

```
When(/^I go to the edit page for "(.*?)"$/) do |title|
  edit_movie_path(Movie.find_by_title(title).id)
end
```

That would generally, in rails example apps, take you to the edit page for the movie with the entered title.